# Hibernate join another joined table

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

Assume that I have three class; UserAccount, UserGroup and Role.

UserGroup and Role are like;

```
public class UserGroup{

.....

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="..." .......)
List<Role> roleList=new ArrayList<Role>();


}

public class Role{
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="roleList")
List<UserGroup> groupList=new ArrayList<UserGroup>();

}
```

I wanna relate my UserAccount class with that joined table which describes relation between UserGroup and Role

```
public class UserAccount{

...

@OneToMany
@JoinTable(???????)
List<???> ??????

}
```

Is there a way to do that?

Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there's a natural way to do this with your current object structure, but that's because your objects aren't defined in a way that suits your needs.

If you want to associate a user account entity with a list of related usergroups and roles rather than just to a usergroup or just to a role, you need to create an entity representing that combination.

It would go approximately as follows:

Instead of having usergroup relate to role in a many-to-many relation defined by a join table, create a `UserGroupWithRole` entity that has a many-to-one relation to both `UserGroup` and to `Role`, and create a relation to a list of `UserGroupWithRole` entities in your `UserAccount`.

Comment: Thank you. So how can i find useraccount of a usergroup with criteria. I tried it but i cant create alias on List

Comment: Navigating these things by criteria can be interesting, but it can be done and likely will involve an alias.  It's worthy of a new question.  Post another question with mapping details and what you're trying to get.  I might answer or someone else might do it first.